# Returning default value from a nested dict lookup in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to perform several lookups in a dictionary, some of which may be lookups to subdictionaries (`d['a'], d['b']['c']['d']['e']`). I'd like to return a default value on `KeyError` at any point in the lookup process, whether it be on the first or nth dictionary. The end goal is to put the return values in a new, flattened dictionary.

Is there a simpler way of doing this than my current:

```
e = {}
try:
    e['a'] = d['a']
except KeyError:
    e['a'] = 0
try:
    e['d'] = d['b']['c']['d']
except KeyError:
    e['d'] = 0

...and so on
```

I've thought about the issue some and considered using `.get()` or using `defaultdict()` or using some sort of recursion, but couldn't come up with any solutions. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break that out into a function:

```
def try_get(dic, default, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            dic = dic[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
    return dic

e['a'] = try_get(d, 0, 'a')
e['d'] = try_get(d, 0, 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: Can we not use `setdefualt`  as I did ?